# SSRS matrix report issue with multiple column group

Tags: ssrs-2008

i have table with below fields like

```
OEREFerence  Rank  Sold   SoldDate
-----------  ----  ----   --------
2Acwqa        1     45    01/02/2010 
2Acwqa        2     40    11/02/2010 
4Xcwqa        1     38    05/02/2010 
4Xcwqa        2     35    15/02/2010
```

oereference is duplicate but their sold date is different

now i want to show the data in my matrix report like

```
             SoldDate     SoldDate
             --------     --------
OEREFerence  Rank1 Sold   Rank2 Sold
-----------  ----- ----   ----- ----
2Acwqa         1    45      2     40
4Xcwqa         1    38      2     35
```

i am new in ssrs. i am confuse how to draw this output. i think i have to create row group on OEreference and first column group on solddate. second child column group on rank and sold field.

please anyone who knows how to bring this output in ssrs then please tell me in detail that in which way i need to create column group. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column group of Rank, then add 2 columns in the same group in matrix. One Column as Rank and other as Sold. I think it will work and you will get the desired output